# Additional Reputation for Upvoted Questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

It just occurred to me that questions that are upvoted more than others are often harder to answer. Therefore, perhaps, a user who provides an accepted answer should get +1, +2, or some other small amount of reputation as bonus per upvote on the *question* for answering a more "difficult/liked" (upvoted) question.

Anybody agree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an interesting idea, but I'm not sure of your premise that questions with more UVs are harder to answer.

The odd tide of votes come and goes, I sure don't know why some things get UVed so much and not others.
I can for sure say that UVs on a question have **no** correlation to the difficulty of the question.

Also UVs on questions should not indicate the popularity of a question; views do that. Now it is true that when a question is [popular](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13828/2217), it gets a lot of views and thus more UVs. But UVs are a measure of how many people found that post useful, not "liked" as in facebook popular.

Take [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6488/2217) as an example; it is about a little known feature, and has only gotten 650 views in 2 years (not a lot). Surely you can't say that it accumulated many UVs because of its popularity, and it sure is not a difficult thing to fix.

In fact some of my most UVed answers are answering simple questions.
[How to convert a single vertex into a plane within a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/35835/2217)
[How to Model a Keyboard key?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/28042/2217)
[Is there a way to make comments in the node editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7825/2217)

See [Why is voting important?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) and [What is voting up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up); they make it clear that when you vote it represents much more then just, for example "you liked the picture," but rather you are playing a part in the whole site wide sorting of content best to worst.

---

However, after saying all that, if you could find a metric to find the truly difficult questions and award good answers a bonus I would be for that.

It might be something like unanswered for more then 3 weeks with more then 4 UVs on the question and less then 100 views, then the bonus kicks in.

Comment: I do have quite a bit to say, so bear with me if it takes a while to type (using the mobile app). The first several things all blend into one: What you suggest in your last paragraph is not at all what I meant, but also, in my opinion, a much better idea (sorry for being unclear). What _I_ was suggesting was a normal accepted answer grants the answerer +15 rep. What I was suggesting was a 0 or <0 upvote question would give an accepted answer +15 rep. A 1 upvote question would give an accepted answer +17 rep. 2 upvotes --> +19 and so on, and so forth.

Comment: Second, you are very correct in saying that upvotes are not a particularly accurate way of measuring a question's difficulty; it was simply what came to mind first. A better metric might be something like what you suggested or something like the following. A DP (Difficulty Point [theoretical]) would add +1 rep to the usual +15 for each of the following. 1.) Asker's rep / 1,000 rounded to nearest 1 (roughly +1 for each 1,000 rep that the asker possesses [makes sense because people w/ more rep/more experience often ask better questions]).

Comment: 2.) +1 for each 5 comments (more comments probably means more difficult things that need to be explained). 3.) +2 for every other answer (if there is only one answer, it's the best, the worst, and everything else. If there are five answers and it's accepted, it's probably the best for that particular case). I'm done now (yay).

Comment: @ShadyPuck you have an interesting and intriguing idea, yet I kinda doubt that we will ever see this on an SE site.Just because I dont know if there is a good way to create the definition for what a difficult question is. Propose it on the [main meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/), but just a warning you probably will be met with DVs.

Comment: I think I will. I'm not sure I should care about DVs, though, because I don't have an account on it yet. Why should people DV it, out of curiosity?

Comment: @ShadyPuck That is just the norm on other large SE sites, SE and the main meta definitely have a tenancy to down vote posts a lot.

Comment: Ah, okay. Noted.